# Lateral communication in Polymer

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, polymer, dom-events

Here is the problem:

Any two Polymer elements may need to communicate. No assumption is made as to where these elements might be in the DOM (or shadow DOM), this means one event cannot simply bubble up to another element.

The good old way to achieve this would have been to let events bubble up to the root node and then fire *broadcast* events on the root node for other elements to listen to.

This approach however breaks encapsulation and seems to go against Polymer's overall design. AngularJS for example provides an event broadcaster that keeps controllers from unnecessarily keeping references to the root node.

Can such approach be achieved with Polymer? Otherwise can this be solved with a different approach?

Comment: link to Polymer [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/145)

Comment: Polymer wants you to avoid having lateral communication and have all communication mediated by a controller. IOW, have an explicit container that knows both targets and manages their communication. As an architecture, it can feel like extra work at first, but ultimately provides vastly more robust designs.

Comment: @ScottMiles this is what I was implying, sorry if the wording was misleading.. Looks like you can use elements as services in Polymer which is even better than controllers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `polymer-signals`

http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#using-ltpolymer-signalsgt

Quoting from the doc:

> Your element fires polymer-signal and names the signal in its payload:

```
this.fire('polymer-signal', {name: "foo", data: "Foo!"});
```

> This event bubbles up to document where a handler constructs and dispatches a new event, polymer-signal-foo, to all instances of . Parts of your app or other Polymer elements can declare a  element to catch the named signal:

```
<polymer-signals on-polymer-signal-foo="{{fooSignal}}"></polymer-signals>
```

Comment: polymer-signals have been renamed core-signals

Comment: No it has bee renamed to iron-signals