# Intercepting click events across Shadow DOM barrier

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, polymer, shadow-dom

In my application, I intercept clicks on links and turn them into AJAX calls in order to achieve Single-Page-App-iness. In jQuery this looks something like this:

```
$('#main').on('click', 'a[href]', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 2 || e.metaKey) return; // don't capture new tab clicks
  /* stuff */
});
```

Recently, however, I have begun using Custom Elements and Shadow DOM. The above code doesn't work on `a` tags which are in shadow trees, as the click event gets retargeted to the shadow host.

**Is it possible to make the above code to work in order to intercept click events that occur in a shadow tree? If not, what is a best practice to continue to achieve this functionality?**

Note: I am using Polymer Platform to polyfill Web Components (though not full Polymer).

Comment: Here's a [reproducible test case](http://jsbin.com/digeputu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

In Polymer ≥0.4.0 you can use the `/deep/` combinator:

```
$('#main').on('click', '* /deep/ a[href]', function() {
  if (e.which == 2 || e.metaKey) return; // don't capture new tab clicks
  /* stuff */
});
```

Note: This technique should be used sparingly, as it's potentially mucking about in the implementation of all components, including some parts of the web platform like `<video>` tags.

Comment: The main problem with this is that you're registering a click handler on every individual `<a>` tag instead of using event delegation. It'll work, but it's probably not efficient.

Comment: Good point. From brief poking around it looks like jQuery doesn't choke on `/deep/` as I expected either, so maybe you can also do it the idiomatic jquery way with delegation.

Comment: I think that may be alright, as I do checks on the URL to make sure it's HTTP(S), not a fragment reference, etc. So it shouldn't break <video> functionality.

Comment: I've updated it to more closely match the original question and also to work across native and non-native shadow dom implementations.

Comment: This doesn't work when window.ShadowDOMPolyfill is truthy (i.e. in Polymer Platform)

Comment: The Polymer platform >=0.4.0 now includes a polyfilled implementation for /deep/ - https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/commit/13e334d

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacking around your existing structure to make it act like a single-page app, you might want to design it that way from the beginning. That will give you the most of Web Component's awesomeness. Here's a [demo](http://polymer-change.appspot.com/demos/spa.html) (and [source](https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-change/blob/master/demos/spa.html)) of a single-page app using Polymer. Even if you don't want to use Polymer, you can probably use `flatiron-director` yourself to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: This is how I've been "designing it that way from the beginning" to be an SPA? Most of the page (including the custom elements) is user-generated content, so I can't control the markup.

That demo doesn't work for me in Firefox.

Comment: Good point. If it's user-generated content, you might be stuck with Peter's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [core-ajax](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax) to handle your ajax calls and some form of [inter-components communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241534/lateral-communication-in-polymer) to update your custom element.

Comment: This isn't a question about Polymer. It's about ShadowDOM/Web Components, which are polyfilled by Polymer *Platform*.